# How to get the estimate from coin::wilcox_test in R

Tags: r

I use coin::wilcox_test for an analysis and am wondering how to get the estimate (difference in location) from it.

```
library(coin)
water_transfer <- data.frame(pd = c(0.80, 0.83, 1.89, 1.04, 1.45, 1.38, 1.91, 1.64, 0.73, 1.46,1.15, 0.88, 0.90, 0.74, 1.21),
age = factor(c(rep("At term", 10), rep("12-26 Weeks", 5))))

wt <- wilcox_test(pd ~ age, data = water_transfer,                     distribution = "exact", conf.int = TRUE)
wt

        Exact Wilcoxon Mann-Whitney Rank Sum Test

data:  pd by age (12-26 Weeks, At term)
Z = -1.2, p-value = 0.3
alternative hypothesis: true mu is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.76  0.15
sample estimates:
difference in location 
                -0.305
```

How to retrieve the "-0.305"?

Comment: that package uses s4 objects, so you can extract things from `wt` with `@` instead of `$` or `[` or you can use some of the generics which they have defined in the package, like `pvalue` or `statistic` or since `wt@confint()` is a function in the object, you can get different confidence levels `wt@confint(.90)$estimate`

Answer (score 3):

Just figured it out:

```
confint(wt)[[2]]
difference in location 
                -0.305
```